# スパム対策でwebサイトのウィジェット内でメッセージ送信に制限を設ける方法

Tags: javascript, html

expressで作ったwebアプリにbotpressのAIチャットボットを埋め込む予定です。
botpressのメッセージ送信数に2000回という制限があるため、ユーザーが一定回数メッセージを送ると、他のページに遷移し、チャットのページに戻れなくする仕組みを作りました。
しかし、botpressのイベント検知はhtmlのscript内で行うので、ブラウザのコンソールからscriptの処理を無効化されるとスパム可能です。スパムを回避するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

[botpressのドキュメント](https://botpress.com/docs/cloud/toolbox/events-triggers/)
以下html

Triggers

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
<script>
    window.botpressWebChat.onEvent(
        function (event) {
            if (event.type === 'MESSAGE.SENT') {
                window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'show' })

                //送信回数を記録する処理
            }
        },
        ['MESSAGE.SENT']
    )
</script>
```